# Non-positional but required argument with argparse

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I have been using optparse module till python 2.6
But as 2.7 documentation says that optparse is deprecated, I am trying to explore argparse

Looks like I am stuck at a point wherein I need to write a script which accepts multiple 'mandatory' arguments where their position is not fixed. In addition it may have optional parameters and flags too
So I need something like:
xyz_script.py --foo  --bar  --flag1 --flag2 --opt1

One way I could think of is using 'required=True' with optional parameters in the argparse but the documentation says that it is not recommended

Is there any other way of achieving this ?

Comment: Don't worry about the 'deprecated' bit.  `optparse` isn't going away.  Making an 'optional' 'required' can lead to confusing terminology.  Still if the argument is mandatory, and needs a clear identifier (flag) go ahead and use the feature.  `optparse` has the same caution about 'required options'.

Comment: A good alternative to making `optionals` required, is to give them sensible defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is talking about having flags (what it refers to as optional arguments) as being required (presumably positional arguments should be used instead).  But if you insist on having them be required, that is the way to do it.

Comment: I agree that documentation recommends positional arguments instead. But in my case their position(order) doesn't matter just that they are mandatory.

So they are REQUIRED but NOT POSITIONAL in my case :)